# Showing Custom image on Right of Push/Local Notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I received a notification from passbook app where i saved my movie ticket that i bought. The notification had 2 image on lock screen: On left it had icon of the original app from where i bought movie tickets and On right side it had image of the passbook ticket information. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

This notification is local and generated by Passbook app.

First i wanted to know how do we add custom image on right side which is not app icon and its a content generated later in app. I am looking to achieve this and hasn't got much info about it.

Second, IS this possible for Push notification too ? If yes ? Is there documentation where its mentioned ?

Edit: I just want to know can above screenshot i shared can be done ? Because Passbook is doing. I need the solution for that even if its just for Local Notification. Thanks.

Comment: The official documentation provides no information about this and I think there is no public API for a notification with an image. Apparently it is possible, but I guess this feature is Apple exclusive at the moment.

Comment: Padam, Did you ever come up with an answer?

Comment: @John Sorry there is no official info about achieving this anywhere. So for now i couldn't get it done. Maybe later in future apple will add provision to do it.

Comment: Padam, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Widget , which is a very good feature of iOS app. In widget you can use custom view in your application for Local Notification . So by using that widget you can show image on right side in notification , even in lockscreen

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to tell it? Any link or example code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No. The notification payload can be up to 256 bytes long. You can send an image only if the encoded image size plus the rest of the payload is no bigger than 256 bytes.

You can, however, use launch-image property from alert apn dictionary to specify an image from app bundle that will be used at app launch.

Or you can send a URL from which the image can be downloaded within the app.

Comment: Thanks for response. But this doesn't answer question at all. I am interested in the "Right" image for local notification !!! Passbook app is doing that. That right content is been generated from app, its not launch-image.